# Hive beginner, got FAILED: SemanticException error

Tags: sql, hive

Suppose I have two tables, actv_user and play_video:

actv_user :

```
 |p_date | user_id|country_name|
| -------- | -------------- |------------|
| 20210125| 1|Brazil|
| 20210124| 2|ENG|
| 20210125| 3|India|
| 20210125| 4|Indonesia|
| 20210125| 5|Indonesia|
| 20210125| 6|Brazil|
| 20210125| 7|Brazil|
| 20210125| 8|Indonesia|
User_id is unique but country_name can be null

play_video:
| user_id| video_id|
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1| 1001|
| 1| 1002|
| 2| 2001|
| 3| 1001|
| 3| 1002|
| 3| 3003|
| 4| 4004|
|5| 1001|
|5| 5005|
|6| 1001|
|6| 1002|
|7| 1001|
|7| 1002|
|8| 3003|
|8| 4004|
```

What I want to do is find New users(p_date = 20210125) in Brazil, Indonesia and India play videos on top  on the first day.
Therefore, new users in Brazil are 1,6,7(user_id), new user in India is 3, new user in Indonesia are 4, 5,8(user_id);
The outcome is something like this:
In Brazil the top videos played by new users are 1001,1002
In India the top videos played by new users are 1001,1002,3003
In Indonesia the top videos played by new users are 4004,3003, 5005

desire outcome:

```
|country_name| count|video_id|
| -------- | -------------- |----- |
| Brazil| 1001|3|
| Brazil| 1002|3|
| India | 1001|1|
| India | 1002|1|
| India | 3003|1|
| Indonesia | 4004|2|
| Indonesia | 3003|1|
| Indonesia | 5005|1|
```

what I got error message is : Failed: semanticexception error condition: user_ ID is not null. Table play is missing in SQL_ Photo partition restrictions! If there is partition condition, please check whether there is abnormal or use, please add bracket for or condition!

any ideas?

I tried:

```
    select actv_user.country_name ,play_video.video_id, count(play_video.video_id) count_num

from  actv_user  join   play_photo on actv_user.user_id  = play_video.user_id 

where p_date = 20210125 and (country_name = 'Brazil' or country_name = 'India ' or country_name = 'Indonesia ')

group by actv_user.country_name ;
```

Comment: and what is partition restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this
country_name in ('Brazil' ,'India ' ,'Indonesia ')